# How to find row index of one column based on values of a different column where the values in the two distinct columns are equal in pandas?

Tags: python

I have some pandas output:

```
seq X1      X2   
0   0.59    NaN  
1   -1.28   NaN  
2   -1.26   NaN 
3   -0.79   NaN 
4   1.03    NaN
5   -1.43   NaN 
6   0.03    1.03    
7   0.92    1.03
8   -2.21   1.03
```

How do I get a third column X3, that takes the 1.03 in X2 and finds the seq number associated with the same number in column X1? In my example starting from row7(row index 6), X3 should return a 4, since seq = 4 when X1 is 1.03.

I desire:

```
seq  X1     X2  X3
0   0.59    NaN  NaN
1   -1.28   NaN  NaN
2   -1.26   NaN  NaN
3   -0.79   NaN  NaN
4   1.03    NaN  NaN
5   -1.43   NaN  NaN
6   0.03    1.03 4  
7   0.92    1.03 4
8   -2.21   1.03 4
```

First ever Stack question. Pardon my folly!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain why you want the number `4` to appear in all rows of `X3`?

You can get the seq value (`4`) where `X1 == 1.03` by typing:

```
df.loc[df['X1']==1.03, 'seq'].values[0]
```

But that only gives you one 4. Note that I've taken the first seq value (by typing `[0]`) because if you have more than one place where `X1 == 1.03` a list of numbers will be returned (as a data frame) and you haven't explained how you'd like to deal with multiple seq matches.

The following code will run and return the data frame you requested, but I suggest you spend a little time thinking about whether you need `X2` and `X3` to be part of the data frame at all...

```
# Import what you need
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Define the data
x1 = np.array([0.59, -1.28, -1.27, -0.79, \
                1.03, -1.43, 0.03, 0.92, -2.21])
x2 = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, \
                np.nan, np.nan, 1.03, 1.03, 1.03])

# Create a pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame( { 'seq' : range(9),
                     'X1'  : x1,
                     'X2'  : x2 } )

# Figure out where the first instance of X1==1.03
# occurs and grab that seq value
s_first = df.loc[df['X1']==1.03,'seq'].values[0]

# Fill in X3 according to the values in X2
df.loc[df['X2'].isnull(), 'X3'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['X2'].notnull(), 'X3'] = s_first

# Show the 9 rows in the data frame
df.head(9)
```

Comment: Kirstie thanks for the response. The real reason I want the number filled in as a 4 is so I can perform a subseqent calculation. You can think of X2 as a rolling calcualtion of X1 (it is a rolling max). I want the 4 in X3 so I can do a subsequent calculation that takes the 'seq' number of X3 and subtracts it from from the current 'seq' number X2. Think of the 'seq' as a period. I want to know the number of periods it has been since items in X2 have occured in X1.

Comment: I set up my question improperly upon further investigation of your response. The s_first solution works for my simple example but I failed to properly state my question in a way that I need the solution to generalize to more cases. I wouldn't be able to hardcode all of the values that X1 could take on that it has in common with X2.

Comment: You can update your question to make it clearer. Feel free to take my code and adjust it to show a more appropriate example.

Comment: You might also find these docs a good jumping off point: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html